# What is flush:post in vue.js watchers?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```js
export default {
  // ...
  watch: {
    key: {
      handler() {},
      flush: 'post'
    }
  }
}
```

what this code do?

can you give me some example?

I am learning vue.js by documentation and can't understand this code. so please help me understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flush: 'post'` option means, that the handler is fired after vue has updated the component and has updated the Browser DOM.

Without this, the handler will be triggered directly when a value changes which does not necessarily means, that vue has already updated the component in the browser. If you want to perform a side effect that requires access to the DOM, you need to make sure, that vue has already done the update of the DOM

I would recommend to check out the [lifecycle documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html) in the vue documentation. This might give you an idea of how the lifecycle work in reactive frameworks.

### Example

Imagine, you change a className based on a state variable. After you changed the class you want to know the height of your element. (The example is in Vue 3 composition API, but it works the same within the Vue 2 options api.)

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const myElement = ref(null);
    const someState = ref(false);

    const rootClasses = computed(() => ({
      'my-class': someState.value,
    }))

    const handleClick = () => {
      someState.value = false;
    }

    watch(
      someState,
      (newSomeState) => {
        if (!myElement.value || !newSomeState) return;
        const height = myElement.offsetHeight;
        // do something with the height here.
      },
      { flush: 'post' }
    );
  }
})
```